# Relation between rotation matrix and euler angles

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, 3d, rotations, angle

I have a rotation matrix $M$ (so I know that $M M^T = 1$). I retrieve the angles with the formulae:
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\alpha & = & {\rm atan2}(M_{1 2}, M_{1 1}) \\
\beta  & = & {\rm atan2}(- M_{1 3}, \sqrt{1 - M_{1 3}^2}) \\
\gamma  & = & {\rm atan2}(M_{2 3}, M_{3 3}) \\
\end{array}
$$

I have my three matrices
$$R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
                        0 & \cos(\gamma) & \sin( \gamma) \\
                        0 & -\sin(\gamma) & \cos( \gamma) \end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_y = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\beta) & 0 & -\sin(\beta) \\
                        0 & 1 & 0 \\
                        \sin(\beta) & 0 & \cos(\beta) \end{bmatrix}$$
$$R_z = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & \sin(\alpha)  & 0 \\
                        -\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\
                         0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now I want to prove that when $0 < \cos(\beta)$ we have

$$ M = R_x R_y R_z$$

I made it for the simple cases ($M_{1 1}$, $M_{1 2}$, $M_{1 3}$, $M_{2 3}$, $M_{3 3}$) but I am stuck on the remaining cases. For example, how can I prove that
$$M_{2 1} = \cos(\alpha) \sin(\beta) \sin(\gamma) - \sin(\alpha) \cos(\gamma)$$

Comment: Lolo  In the first three equations (defining $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\gamma$ did you mean "tan2" to mean $\tan^2$, or is the 2 a multiple of what follows?

Comment: no I mean the function atan2 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Thank you for answering, and you're welcome for the edit, accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution***

Ok after thinking over it is sufficient to multiply both sides by $\cos^2(\beta)$. This leads to
$$M_{2 1}  (1 - M_{1 3}^2) = - M_{1 1} M_{2 3} M_{1 3} -
                       M_{1 2} M_{2 2}$$
which can easily be checked.